# How to kill localdb process after exit application

Tags: .net, winforms, localdb

I am developing winform application.

Connection string of my db as below;

```
string _DatabaseFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Database\db.mdf";
                _DatabaseConnectionParams = String.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True", _DatabaseFile);
```

Everyting works good.

But  SQL Server process continues to work after exit my application.

Which approach is good to stop SQL Server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should close / dispose of the connections.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i dispose all connection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to do anything.

It shuts down automatically a few minutes after the last connection to the process is closed.